# How to change material on runtime using OBJ/MTL Loader

Tags: javascript

I can`t change material on runtime I can change the materials while loading mesh/materials by MTLLoader.

```
objLoader.load( settings.OBJName + '.obj', function ( object ) {

                geodesic = object; // reference doesnt work outside the function

                object.traverse(function(node) {
                    //node.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

                    if(node.material !== undefined) {           // przebieg po wszystkich obiektach MeshPhongMaterial
                        node.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
                        //console.log(node.material);


                    if(node.material.name == 'tubes') {
                        node.material.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
                        node.material.shininess = 20;
                        node.material.reflectivity = 0.5;


                        node.material.specular = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
                    }
                    else if(node.material instanceof Array)     // przebieg po tablicach obiektow MeshPhongMaterial
                    {

                        var arrayLen = node.material.length;
                        for(var i=0; i<arrayLen; i++) {
                            node.material[i].side = THREE.DoubleSide;
                        }
                    }
                }

                 });
```

OK and how to change loaded materials on runtime ? Is there any way ? Refference object inside function is invisible outside the function.